# Heroku ACM SSL says Cert issued but certificate won't show on the website

Tags: ssl, heroku

This is my first time getting an SSL certificate for my website. I followed this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management
heroku certs:auto displays that Status is "Cert issued". I get no errors. I use git push and the website is still not certified. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information - like what you get from 'heroku domains' command, and what kind of "not certified" problem. Is there no cert at all, or is the browser saying cert is invalid?

Comment: how exactly are you accessing the app? Through the heroku default subdomain? 

Or your custom domain with a `CNAME`? 

(if it's the `CNAME`, are you pointing it to the right name on heroku? You'll see your SSL endpoint when you call `heroku certs` )

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if anyone else runs into this problem, which I was just battling myself, here was my problem:

When following the Heroku dev center guide on how to point a custom domain to your herokuapp, the guide says, among other things:

> "Create a CNAME record to map from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.herokuapp.com or your SSL endpoint if using SSL."

Neither one of these alternatives are, however, the way to go now (SSL endpoint is considered legacy at Heroku). Instead, once you have added your custom domain correctly, simply:

1. In Heroku CLI, run "heroku certs:auto:enable" to enable ACM.
2. Point your domain's DNS records at the Heroku DNS target for your custom domain, which you can find by running "heroku domains"
3. Wait a little.

This should do it.